# Version issue in custom jar

Tags: java

I am posting this question as I have limited resources to test or confirm by my own.
Problem statement : I have an old custom Jar working with java 1.6. We don't have source code as well.
To fix one of the issue we updated 2 .class file of this jar using 7-zip.The code change  was just to update the existing loggers with more meaningful messages.
These 2 .class file compiled with java 1.7.
Now the questions is whether this jar will work correctly with java 1.6 or will generate java version issue as 2 of the .class files are compiled with java 1.7.
Note - I know it's easy to test this rather then asking here but my test environment is only supporting java 1.8 and it's working perfectly but whether it will run with java 1.6 or not I can't test.

Comment: If it's important to you that your code work right under Java 1.6, it seems to me that you don't want to rely on anything you might get here.  Rather, you should test your code under 1.6 to see if it works.  With so many virtualization options available to you (Docker, vargrant, cloud computing, etc.), there should be no reason you can't come up with a 1.6 environment to test with.

Comment: The two answers that have been given so far make my point.  One says "yes", the other says "no".  I say find out for sure by doing your own testing, using whatever advice you get here as a starting point for that testing. - With that said, I had in mind what @rzwitserloot was saying...that you can compile with 1.7 but tell the compiler to target 1.6 compatibility.  It's probably safe to assume that this solution will give you a compatible build.  If you should test depends, I guess, on the consequences of getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile using: `javac Foo.java` where that `javac` is from a JDK1.7 installation, and you then attempt to run the class file that results on a JDK1.6, it **will not work**.

However, all you need to do is this:

`javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 Foo.java`, and then it will, unless you used features from 1.7. If you use language features (I can't think of any, so I doubt it), it won't compile, and thus you know. If you use API, it *will* compile and you *won't know*. There is no easy solution to this other than compiling with JDK1.6 (or compiling with javac7 against a bootcp of JDK1.6, but you need to download and install a JDK1.6 to get that; might as well just use javac6 then).

Answer (score 0):

**Binary Compatibility**

The class file version for Java SE 7 is 51, as per the JVM Specification, because of the invokedynamic byte code introduced by JSR 292. Version 51 class files produced by the Java SE 7 compiler cannot be used in Java SE 6.

Java SE 7 is binary-compatible with Java SE 6 except for the [incompatibilities](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities) . Except for the noted incompatibilities, class files built with the Java SE 6 compiler will run correctly in Java SE 7.

**Friends Words ...** 
The compiler is not backwards compatible because bytecode generated with Java7 JDK won't run in Java 1.6 jvm (unless compiled with the -target 1.6 flag). But the JVM is backwards compatible, as it can run older bytecodes.

So   they chose to consider the compatibility from the point of view of javac (as it is the part specific to the JDK), meaning that the bytecode generated can be run in future releases of the jvm (that is more related to the JRE, but also bundled in the JDK).

In brief, we can say:

```
JDK's are (usually) forward compatible.
JRE's are (usually) backward compatible.
```

**Java Says**

**Cross-Compilation Options**

By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap and extension classes of the platform that javac shipped with. But javac also supports cross-compiling, where classes are compiled against a bootstrap and extension classes of a different Java platform implementation. It is important to use -bootclasspath and -extdirs when cross-compiling; see Cross-Compilation Example below.

```
-target version
    Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM. Class files will run on the specified target and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM. Valid targets are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and 1.7 (also 7).

    The default for -target depends on the value of -source:

        If -source is not specified, the value of -target is 1.7
        If -source is 1.2, the value of -target is 1.4
        If -source is 1.3, the value of -target is 1.4
        If -source is 1.5, the value of -target is 1.7
        If -source is 1.6, the value of -target is 1.7
        For all other values of -source, the value of -target is the value of -source.

-bootclasspath bootclasspath
    Cross-compile against the specified set of boot classes. As with the user class path, boot class path entries are separated by colons (:) and can be directories, JAR archives, or ZIP archives.
```

**For More about Cross-Compilation look at**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options

**Better than me at**
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html

Answer (score -1):

The code base for Java 7 and versions of Java 6 is very similar and even shares many of the same bugs. e.g. the was a well known bug in Java 7 when it was released to do with loop optimisation and people suggested waiting for it to be fixed before migrating. The interesting thing was the bug was also in Java 6, the only difference was that the optimisation was on by default in Java 7 and off by default in Java 6.

Most of the performance improvements in Java 7 were back ported into Java 6.

Comment: You seem to be talking about API compatibility. I think the bigger issue, and likely what the OP is asking about, is bytecode compatibility.  The `-target` option to the compiler is there for a reason, I'd think.